# What causes the beep on the hour?

Tags: notification, time

I admit this isn't a really dramatic issue, but I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.10 on a fairly new laptop. Now that I got the sound working, I hear a beep every hour on the hour, coming from the speakers. I'm not imagining things. I have no idea what produces the beep: there is no fancy timer or alarm clock app running on this system. There is nothing in my `crontab`, and `cron.hourly` is empty.
The sound could be `/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/click.ogg`, but I'm not sure.

What causes the beep? What do I do to turn it off?

EDIT: it could also be `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/message.oga`.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the system log?

Comment: @Raffles There is nothing in the syslog that could refer to an hourly beep.